# WPF TextBox in not cleared when the data is out of range

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox

I write small WPF application ,In my app I have one field call 'Seq' which is actually the byte data. 
I have used WPF binding for converting the Hex String entered in text box to Bye data. It works fine from TextBox to source, but I want text (data type in textbox) to be cleared itself when the source value is out of range. But the text box never gets updated/cleared when the value is out of range.

Please see my code snippet of individual files ( xaml,viewModel,Converter).

**1)    Converter for HexString to Byte**

```
public class StringToByteConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    //hex string to byte array
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is String)
        {
            string valueTyped = (String)value;
            try
            {
                return Enumerable.Range(0, valueTyped.Length)
                            .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                            .Select(x => System.Convert.ToByte(valueTyped.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                            .ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //clear the text box 
                return new byte[] { 0x00 };
            }

        }
        return new byte[] {0x00};
    }
}
```

**2) ViewModelProperty**

```
public class WProtocol
    {
        private byte[] _seq = new byte[1] { 0x00 };

        public byte[] Seq
        {
            get { return _seq; }
            set
            {
                _seq = value;
            }
        }      
    }
```

**3)xaml for TextBox Binding**

```
<Grid>
            <Label Content="Sequence :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="29,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="115,26,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Seq, Converter= {StaticResource StringToByteConverter},Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="67" FontSize="9" FontFamily="Arial"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="282,28,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69"/>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: In order to update the TexBox from the view model property, you would have to implement the converter's Convert method.

Comment: Hi Clemens, can you tell me please , how should be implemented the convert method to update the text box?

Comment: You have already written the conversion from string to byte[]. Just also write the other direction.